# Trying to read the previous line when reading a certain line from a text file in C#

Tags: c#

I'm reading a text file that contains continents , countries , capitals and the population of those countries. Here is the text file [image of file with info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQYSM.png). I then input a value , let's say I input "Birmanie" the `StreamReader` instance then takes the info from the NEXT line which would be "Bolivie". "Pays" is the input. My goal is to read the line of the country that the user inputs and then later on extract the info from that line.

Here's my code.

```cs
while (!srRecherche.EndOfStream)
{
    lireLigneRechercher = srRecherche.ReadLine();

    if (lireLigneRechercher.IndexOf(Pays,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 35; i++)
        {
            lireCharacteres += (char)srRecherche.Read();
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= 74; i++)
        {
            srRecherche.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

The `for` loops are there so that I can skip through the rest of the information and only read the country's name.

Comment: I would start by creating a class that has properly typed properties for each of those 4 values (say `class CountryData`). Then I'd create a `List<CountryData>`. Finally, I'd read in each line, parse out the four fields, create a `ContryData` instance and add it to the list. Now that you have all the data available, I could do whatever I wanted. Trying to use a text file like a database (particularly one where the lines are not equal length) will be a very frustrating experience

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that might help. The numbers (index positions on the lines) are completely made up, but hopefully you'll see where I'm going. Instead of trying to read with a reader, I would read all the lines and put them into a collection of some sort. I used a struct and a HashSet below, but you could use a class and a List, or a SortedSet, or a Collection, or many other options. By transforming each line into a struct/class, you gain the liberty of doing any sort of analysis or manipulation you want without having to back-track. Since your data seems relatively fixed, you can also gain some advantage by storing the entire list in memory and then finding (in your cached list) what the user asks for with a Where() or FirstOrDefault() instead of reading the file with each new input.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string userInput = "Birmanie";

        var lines = File.ReadAllLines("c:\\myfile.txt");

        HashSet<FileLine> fileLines = new();
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            var fileLine = new FileLine()
            {
                Country = line.Substring(0, 25).Trim(),
                City = line.Substring(35, 20).Trim(),
                Population = Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(55, 20).Trim()),
                Continent = line.Substring(75).Trim()
            };

            fileLines.Add(fileLine);
        }


        int pop = fileLines.FirstOrDefault(l => l.City == userInput).Population;
    }
}

struct FileLine
{
    public string Country;
    public string City;
    public int Population;
    public string Continent;
}
```